# Удалене объектов с одинаковыми полями

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist

У меня ест ькласс `Human` c полями

```
private String name;
private String age;
private String weight;
```

Я создаю объекты класса и сохраняю их в List. Как мне убрать из списка объекты. с одинаковым полем `name`и оставить их всег ов одном экземпляре?

Или как мне переопределить методы `equals()` и `hashCode()` для TreeSet?

Comment: перед добалением нового обьекта прочесываете лист и спрашивайте есть ли такое имя в списке, если есть не заносите. Этот способ простой и ефективный если записей мало и добаление происходит не часто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для достижения вашей цели не обязательно переопределять equals и hashcode, но для работы с `TreeSet` ваш класс должен реализовать интерфейс `Comparable`, в противном случае поймаете `ClassCastException`:

```
class Human implements Comparable<Human> {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String weight;

    public Human(String name, String age, String weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Human o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

либо можно создасть коллекцию с помощью компаратора:

```
Set<Human> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Human::getName));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
{
    return this.name == ((Human)obj.name);
}
```

Вот так можно перегрузить метод Equals.

Comment: А что будет, если в качестве `obj` передать не инстанс класса `Human`?

Comment: будет InvalidCastException. Если вы хотите сравнивать объекты различных типов на одинаковые поля, тогда нужно оба класса унаследовать от одного класса, у которого есть это поле. То есть, унаследовать второй класс от этого же класса Human.